# Graphics using chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, charts

Im trying to develop some donut graphics using chart.js but I cant figure out how to write inside the graphic and how to make the graphic thiner.

This is what I have develope in javascript:

```
var config = {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [
                    data.VSTPS_OEEDATOF[0].PctOEE,
                    "100" - data.VSTPS_OEEDATOF[0].PctOEE,
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#979494",
                    "#FFFFFF",
                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
        }
    };

    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
    window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

And this is my html:

```
 <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:18%">
            <canvas id="chart-area" />
        </div>
```

This is what it looks like once its running:

[Donut pie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAAMe.png)

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advise!

Answer (score 0):

If someone is wondering how I solve the problem here is how:

I just add the following plugin to my js code:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
        beforeDraw: function (chart) {
            if (chart.config.options.elements.center) {
                //Get ctx from string
                var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

                //Get options from the center object in options
                var centerConfig = chart.config.options.elements.center;
                var fontStyle = centerConfig.fontStyle || 'Arial';
                var txt = centerConfig.text;
                var color = centerConfig.color || '#000';
                var sidePadding = centerConfig.sidePadding || 20;
                var sidePaddingCalculated = (sidePadding / 100) * (chart.innerRadius * 2)
                //Start with a base font of 30px
                ctx.font = "30px " + fontStyle;

                //Get the width of the string and also the width of the element minus 10 to give it 5px side padding
                var stringWidth = ctx.measureText(txt).width;
                var elementWidth = (chart.innerRadius * 2) - sidePaddingCalculated;

                // Find out how much the font can grow in width.
                var widthRatio = elementWidth / stringWidth;
                var newFontSize = Math.floor(30 * widthRatio);
                var elementHeight = (chart.innerRadius * 2);

                // Pick a new font size so it will not be larger than the height of label.
                var fontSizeToUse = Math.min(newFontSize, elementHeight);

                //Set font settings to draw it correctly.
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                var centerX = ((chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2);
                var centerY = ((chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2);
                ctx.font = fontSizeToUse + "px " + fontStyle;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;

                //Draw text in center
                ctx.fillText(txt, centerX, centerY);
            }
        }
    });
```

And also add the elements "element" on the options part inside the configuration of the chart:

```
 options: {
            responsive: true,
            elements: {
                center: {
                    text: '50%',
                    fontStyle: 'Roboto',
                    sidePadding: 20
                }
            },
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    };
```

Thats all!